# How to add jbuilder property by string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, string, hashmap, jbuilder

I am using rails and jBuilder to serve JSON in my app. I am trying to iterate through various colors to only add them to the resulting JSON if their value is not nil. This is what I am using, which works, but I would like to learn how to pr

> Working code

```
json.cost do
  unless card.cost_red.nil? 
    json.red card.cost_red
  end
  unless card.cost_white.nil? 
    json.white card.cost_white
  end
  unless card.cost_blue.nil? 
    json.blue card.cost_blue
  end
end
```

> Non-working code

```
json.cost do
    ["red", "white", "blue"].each { |color| 
      unless card["cost_" + color].nil?
        json[color] card["cost_" + color]
      end
    }
end
```

The 'json[color]' part is the culprit because if I just use json.blah it works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try replacing "red", "white", "blue" with :red, :white, :blue?

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
json.cost ["red", "white", "blue"] do |color|
  unless card["cost_" + color].nil?
    json.set! color, card["cost_" + color]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is really close but this creates an object for each color, I am looking to have one object with all of the colors within it.

Comment: can you update your answer with the response that you might be expecting?